# how to prevent xpath adding commas on encountered tags

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

How do I modify the following xpath command not to add commas on any child tags?

```
xpath('/a//text()').extract()
```

The current output is

```
C,-(,K,1,, ,K,2,)-convexity
```

but what I want instead:

```
C-(K1, K2)-convexity
```

The relevant part of page source:

```
<a href=".."><i>C</i>-(<i>K</i><sub>1</sub>, <i>K</i><sub>2</sub>)-convexity</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like all you want to do is strip the html tags, after capturing the 'a' tag, so I'd use regex for that:

```
In [3]: import re
In [4]: [re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', x) for x in response.xpath('/a').extract()]
Out[4]: [u'C-(K1, K2)-convexity']
```

Note that extract returns a list, so we need list comprehension and this will return a list.

P.S. I am not saying that this is a better solution than alecxe's. I am just putting it here as another option.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add the regex inside `';'.join()` so that the commas inside single anchor items don't mix with commas between multiple anchors.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong in the xpath you've provided, it's just returning multiple results, a list, which you need to [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to make a single string:

```
>>> ''.join(response.xpath('/a//text()').extract())
u'C-(K1, K2)-convexity'
```

This is from [Scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html).

---

If this value is going to be a [`scrapy.Field`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#item-fields) value - it would be better to make use of [Output Processors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#module-scrapy.contrib.loader.processor).

Comment: Any way to edit this so that multiple a's found would be separated with semicolon? Now there's no separator at all.

Comment: @user1892697 yup, just try `';'.join(response.xpath('/a//text()').extract())`. Does it work for you?

Comment: nope, this will add semicolons also within a's, i.e. `C;-(;K;1;, ;K;2;)-convexity`

Comment: @user1892697 try iterating through the a elements with something like: `';'.join([e.xpath('string(.)')[0].extract() for e in response.xpath('/a')])`

Comment: @elias thanks, this works perfectly (and the output is identical to todinov's `';'.join([re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', x) for x in response.xpath('/a').extract()])`).